# How to select element by css selector

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hey im trying to make typingtest bot but im getting error while selecting element by css selector.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver. Chrome (service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
                        options=options)


words= []


url = "https://typetest.io/"
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(3)


class_name = "fc-button-label"
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, class_name) 
element.click()

input_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, "test-input")

words_elements = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[test-word]')
```

Im gettting error I dont know why

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\js\hello.py", line 32, in <module>
    words_elements = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[test-word]')
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 739, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting error, because you used incorrect selector.

Word selector in you case is:

```py
words_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.test-word')
```

You don't have attribute `test-word`, like you mentioned, you have class `.test-word` instead.